# Why wrapAll() copy javascript code?

Tags: jquery

i have a javascript code and you can see its jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XwQnp/).

when wrap all .inner elements with new div, it seems jquery copy javascript code (so you can see two alert when run).
is this a normal behaviour of `wrapAll()` or this is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the `<script>` tag you have within the element is reevaluated when you wrap it because the dom is rewritten, therefore adding another `click` callback. The solution is to move the `<script>` code with the `click` callback outside of the div.

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(".inner span").click(function() {
     alert(1);
   });
</script>
<div class="inner">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, Although you may want to move it to after the div so that it still binds the click event.